# How to block and unblock https access on OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, network

I am working on a test project that requires me to block https access for a specific app on my Mac (OS X 10.9).

The instruction provided are "Chinese" to me and I have no idea where to start:

(Example: Alter the iptables)
Steps:

1. Block the port:

   ```
   root@QA9:/opt/appname/appnamerouter2# iptables --list
   root@QA9:/opt/appname/appnamerouter2# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 443/8443 -j DROP
   root@QA9:/opt/appname/appnamerouter2# iptables --list
   ```
2. For Open the Port:

   ```
   root@QA9:/opt/appname/appnamerouter2# iptables -D INPUT 1
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe editing your host file could help. You can find some help here about editing host files:

http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-leopard/

Little Snitch is proprietary, the open source software I use for this is 'gas mask' :

http://www.clockwise.ee/gasmask/

Comment: Editing host file won't selectively block the ssl ports and leave the other ports open. That might be sufficient for the testing needs, but I would guess they wouldn't have identified iptables to block specific ports if a broader / easier to accomplish block was feasible.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an answer in regards of the commands you have but a quick solution/workaround might be [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) which doesn't force you to learn the terminal commands - but does need a little work to learn how to engage it selectively.

It's a graphical tool which makes some people much more comfortable when configuring an application firewall. It also comes with great support and several nice guides for getting started.